# android application crashes when button is clicked

Tags: android

I am writing an android application that check the username and the password of the user once a login button is clicked

i run the app in the emulator and when i click on login button the application is crashed

```
package com.google.android.InitialScreen;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TabHost;


public class InitialScreen extends TabActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    EditText username; 
    EditText password;
    Button login;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernamefield);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordfield);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1")
                .setIndicator("TAB 1")
                .setContent(R.id.tabview1));

        this.login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);

        this.login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if ((username.getText().length()==0)&&(password.getText().length()==0))
                    username.setText("u&p");
//                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Username and Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else if ((username.getText().length()==0)){
                    username.setText("u");
//                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (password.getText().length()==0)
                    username.setText("p");
                else 
                    username.setText("ok");
            }
        });
              mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2")
                .setIndicator("TAB 2")
                .setContent(R.id.tabview2));

              mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: No one is going to help you without one, an error message, and two, without some effort on your part to format your post properly.

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess you should init username and password AFTER calling

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Just a guess. Post your stack trace - this might really help.

Comment: Yes, this is the OP's problem. `username` and `password` are both `null`, so the click listener throws a `NullPointerException`.